# How to get recipient's name and head icon in gmail

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, gmail, firefox-addon-sdk, gmail-api

I'm building a firefox addon, I want to get the recipient's name and head icon when composing email or replying, I can easily get the name by using this [gmail.js](https://github.com/KartikTalwar/gmail.js), But I can not figure out how to get the head icon (avatar), is there any API or something can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just get the element from the page?

```
var largeThumbUrl = document.getElementById(':ge').firstChild.src;
var smallThumbUrl = document.getElementById(':0_0-e').src;
```

Comment: It's a good solution but not a great one. Relying on the API is best, as html changes may mess stuff up. And Gmail has frames I think so you have deal with finding right frame. Api is best, but nice of you to look into the dom for this guy.

Comment: Thanks for answering, But as I know, the id or class or other properties will change (very frequently). So this method won't last long time.

Comment: And actually the Id or class is totally random...So it's not so easy to get them.

Comment: To be fair, `gmail.js` is also pretty hacky at best; it's not official and relies on similar things.